# How would I pull data from two tables using one variable that both tables have?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Lets say I have a variable 'userid', I want to select from aspnet_Membership AND aspnet_AccountProfile tables.  They both have the column userid, I just want to be able to make a statement like SELECT * FROM aspnet_AccountProfile, aspnet_Membership WHERE UserId=@UserId and it gets the records with the matching user id for BOTH tables.  how do I do this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a `JOIN`:

There are several basic types of join based on what data exactly you want.  These are related to set theory/relational algebra.  I'll list the most common ones:

**INNER JOIN**

Use this when you want to return every possible combination of rows where both tables have a matching UserId.  Some rows in *either* table may not get returned in an inner join.

```
SELECT * FROM aspnet_AccountProfile INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership
ON aspnet_AccountProfile.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId
```

Another way of writing an INNER JOIN (Which I wouldn't encourage if you want to understand joins) is:

```
SELECT * FROM aspnet_AccountProfile, aspnet_Membership
WHERE aspnet_AccountProfile.UserId = aspnet_membership.UserId
```

Of course, to select the specific UserId you want, you add a condition on *either* table eg:

AND aspnet_AccountProfile.UserId = @UserId

OR

AND aspnet_Membership.UserId = @UserId

Either of those two will work fine for an inner join.

**LEFT OUTER JOIN**

Use this when you want to return *all* rows from the first table in your query, and every combination where the UserId in the second table matches the first.  Some rows in the second table (Membership, in this case) may not get returned at all.

```
SELECT * FROM aspnet_AccountProfile LEFT JOIN aspnet_Membership
ON aspnet_AccountProfile.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId
```

You have to use the left column to narrow down your criteria in this case, or it will automatically get converted to an INNER JOIN.

WHERE aspnet_AccountProfile.UserId = @UserId

**RIGHT OUTER JOIN**

This is fairly uncommon, because it can usually be written as a LEFT outer join.  It's like a left outer join, but all rows from the second table in the relation are returned instead of the first.

```
SELECT * FROM aspnet_AccountProfile RIGHT JOIN aspnet_Membership
ON aspnet_AccountProfile.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId
```

**FULL OUTER JOIN**

Use this if you need to relate all the rows with a matching UserId in AccountProfile to the corresponding rows in Membership, but also need to know which rows in *either* table don't have a match in the other one.

```
SELECT * FROM aspnet_AccountProfile FULL OUTER JOIN aspnet_Membership
ON aspnet_AccountProfile.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId
```

Getting results for only a single user is a little trickier in a FULL OUTER JOIN.  You have to specify that a NULL or the correct value is okay in either table.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi,

you can do it by using

> "SELECT * FROM aspnet_AccountProfile
>   ap, aspnet_Membership m WHERE
>   ap.UserId=m.UserId ANB
>   ap.UserId=@UserId"

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by inner join.

Here is the example,

```
 Select aspnet_Membership.*, aspnet_AccountProfile.* from aspnet_AccountProfile 
inner join aspnet_Membership on aspnet_Membership.userid = aspnet_AccountProfile.userid 
where aspnet_Membership.UserId=@UserId
```

This will get only the record whem userid is common in both the table.

If you want to get the record which are in 1 table and may or may not be in other then you must user the left join

that is

```
 Select aspnet_Membership.*, aspnet_AccountProfile.* from aspnet_AccountProfile 
left join aspnet_Membership on aspnet_Membership.userid = aspnet_AccountProfile.userid 
where aspnet_Membership.UserId=@UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Join.

Something like:

```
Select * from aspnet_AccountProfile INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership
ON aspnet_AccountProfile.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId
Where aspnet_AccountProfile.UserId = @UserId
```

Thanks,
Vamyip

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple inner join for this.